# Undefined User w/ Discord.js (Avatar Command)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm having issues with message.mentions, i'm unable to define the user tagged with this code - any ideas?

```
exports.run = (client, msg, args, config, bot, users) => {
const Discord = require ('discord.js');
   console.log(user);
     if (message.content.startsWith('>av')) {
     var user = message.mentions.user();
     if(!user) user = message.author;
     const av = new Discord.RichEmbed()
       .setTitle(client.user.tag, 'Avatar')
       .setImage(user.displayAvatarURL + '?size=512&f=.gif')
       .setColor("BLACK")
         msg.channel.send(av)
         msg.delete();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us any more about the symptoms?

Comment: You are calling `console.log(user)` before `user` is defined. Also, you have a bunch of references to `message` which probably need to be `msg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code may work, I didn't test it and I also use ea different version of discord.js then most people. If it doesn't work lemme know.

```
exports.run = (client, msg, args, config, bot, users) => {
const Discord = require ('discord.js');
   console.log(user);
     if (msg.content.startsWith('>av')) {
     var user = msg.mentions.users.first() || msg.author;
     const av = new Discord.RichEmbed()
       .setTitle(client.user.tag, 'Avatar')
       .setImage(user.displayAvatarURL + '?size=512&f=.gif')
       .setColor("BLACK")
         msg.channel.send(av)
         msg.delete();
  }
}
```